# Accidentally deleted app/etc/ files

Tags: magento2

For curiosity I try to delete the files in `app/etc` folder. I don't have any back up file for this. And when I try to run the cli magento `magento list` I got this error :

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/php-file
iterator:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71
```

From above error message my `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` is no longer exist.

How to solve this problem without having to restore the deleted files ?

Comment: install new Magento and then you can copy those files from new Magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stupid move to removing the files inside `app/etc`.

I tried [Pavan Kumar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192316/56372) Solutions, and looking for the files in [magento github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/app/etc).

But it doesn't work as expected, Since I don't have the backup file for this the easy way to solve this problem is copy all etc files from your team mate and it will solve it.

It is a good idea to include the etc files in you VCS.

Answer (score 1):

This is your missing file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/code/*/*/cli_commands.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/code/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/design/*/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/i18n/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/internal/*/*/registration.php';
$pathList[] = dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/lib/internal/*/*/*/registration.php';
foreach ($pathList as $path) {
    // Sorting is disabled intentionally for performance improvement
    $files = glob($path, GLOB_NOSORT);
    if ($files === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('glob() returned error while searching in \'' . $path . '\'');
    }
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        include $file;
    }
}
```

app\etc\vendor_path.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Path to Composer vendor directory
 */
return './vendor';
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps, so that it will be useful to the community.

Comment: Nope this one doesnt work for me but thanks again upvoted.